# Has anyone else seen this datagridview bug?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, datagridview

Can anyone explain this?

This works

```
        TrandetlDataGridView.ReadOnly = False
        TrandetlDataGridView.CurrentRow.ReadOnly = True
```

This does not

```
        TrandetlDataGridView.ReadOnly = True
        TrandetlDataGridView.CurrentRow.ReadOnly = False
```

Comment: My question is, why would you need to do the latter?  The default behavior of the grid works essentially the same if the current row is always editable.

Comment: I wouldn't need to use the first example.  I just thought it was interesting that it does work that way but not the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataGridView.ReadOnly` property will OVERRIDE any row/col/cell read only property “IF” the grids read only property is set to `true`. This can be seen in the second posted code that “doesn’t” work.

As per [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.readonly?view=netframework-4.8) documentation for the `DataGridViewRow.ReadOnly` property in the remarks section…

> Setting this property has no effect if the value of the
>   DataGridView.ReadOnly property is true.

A possible solution is to leave the “grids” read only property as `false`, then loop through the grid rows and set each row’s read only property to `true`. Then, it should work as expected.

The example below is in C#, however the same idea would apply using VB.

First a method to loop through the grid and set each row’s read only property to `true`…

```
private void SetRowsReadOnly() {
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in TrandetlDataGridView.Rows) {
    row.ReadOnly = true;
  }
}
```

Then, using your “doesn’t work” example, replace setting the grids read only property with a call to the method above and it should work as expected.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  SetRowsReadOnly();
  TrandetlDataGridView.CurrentRow.ReadOnly = false;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this an let you know.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you, it has been driving me crazy.